# Cannot save the output from a unix executable

Tags: macos, terminal, osx-mavericks, terminal.app

I am attempting to save the output of an application I wrote. When I try to save the output by redirecting stdout the file that it results in is blank.

This is what I am typing into Terminal.app (OS X 10.9.2):

```
./AppName > test.txt
```

The application outputs text via an NSLog().

I get the NSLog() output in Terminal.app, but the resulting text.txt file is blank. I read that I may need to run the app by replacing ./ with the file path:

```
appPath > text.txt
```

The same thing happens.

Could someone please explain to me what the problem is?

Comment: Are you logging to `STDERR`?

Comment: As far as I know NSLog() writes to stderr.

Comment: That is what I thought.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd need to merge `STDERR` to `STDOUT`.  Say:

```
./AppName > test.txt 2>&1
```

and you'd see the *output* in `test.txt`.

Answer (score 1):

NSLog() logs to the Apple System Log (ASL) facility, not stdout or stderr.

Go see the "All Messages" log stream in Console.app or type `syslog` in Terminal. Also, you can set up filters to get ASL to send all log messages from your app to a specific text file. See the manpages for ASL, syslog, etc.

Answer (score 0):

First some background information:

By default a normal unix program starts with two file descriptors: StdOut and StdErr.
StdOut is done via file descriptor number 1.
StdErr is done via file descriptor number 2.

Redirecting standard out is done via `1>`. Example `./App 1> my_log.txt`
Redirecting standard error is done via `2>`. Example `./App 2> my_errors.txt`

<sup>(`>` and `1>` are the same. One is just a shorter notation)</sup>

This allows useful things like only logging errors, or logging the normal output to one file and the errors to a different file. Or the very useful case of logging the normal output to a file and still getting any errors displayed on your screen.

Replacing ./Appname with the full file path will not make any difference. One starts the app from the current directory, one specifies to the full path to the App. Neither influences the file descriptors.

---

Now we finally get to the answer to your question:

What you want to do it to log the output from NSlog(). To do that you first find out where nslog is writing to.

According to [this a question on our sistersite StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7271528/how-to-nslog-into-a-file) NSLog outputs to ASL (Apple's version of syslog) and to console.

Thus you either want to read the output from the systemlog, or change the output from the log to a place where you can easily intercept it. E.g. with `freopen([path cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding], "a+", stderr);`

Several method on how to do that are answered in the [so] post I linked to. If you add more details to your post (e.g. is modifying the application allowed?) then I can answer in more detail.